# Google Smart Lock for Passwords - multiple websites with the single app

Tags: android, google-api, google-smartlockpasswords

I have multiple websites for different counties, such as:

- example.com.th
- example.com.sg
- example.com.vn

All those websites are associated with the single app, BUT credentials on those websites are not shared (a user can have different accounts with the same email/password for different counties, those are not connected, this is by design - cannot change). Inside the app, you can toggle between the countries and then choose to sign in.

Thus I have a problem differentiating between credentials coming from Smart Lock API - you never know what website exactly those credentials came from.
And vice versa, if I save new credentials with the app - Chrome will use it as a hint to sign in user on every website (but it should have a bond only with the proper country).

Is there any way to filter by domain during credentials query & save calls?